# Sharing an object in simperium, write_access doesnt do anything

Tags: simperium

I have created two users, and if i create a bucket for one user and an object inside that bucket i can share it using the HTTP api at the moment.. see here

https://simperium.com/docs/reference/http/#objectshare

However, even when i sent through "write_access" = true and get a 200 as a result, it doesnt seem to let me write to it.
Its only if i enable sharing back the other way that it allows data to sync both ways, am i doing something wrong?

Has collaboration got any further yet? i can see there is a long but no docs as yet? anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial & error, I found the solution:

to edit the shared object, the target user (ie the user that the object was shared with) needs to use an objectId that is equal to: `<original_user_simperiumId>/<original_objectId>` to edit the object.

If you just use `<original_objectId>` it won't work.

So the full command for editing a shared object, using curl:

`curl -H 'X-Simperium-Token: {auth_token_of_target_user}' https://api.simperium.com/1/{appID}/{entity}/i/{original_user_simperiumId>/{original_objectId} -d '{"data_key" : "new_data_value"}'`